# sublime text2 and autocomplete for latex

Tags: autocomplete, latex, sublimetext2

I like using Sumlime Text2 for programming, and these days I also want to write documents in Latex in Sublime Text2. I followed the tutorial online to install latextools and I can edit and generate files successful.

However, I found the auto-complete does not work: e.g.
if I type in \begin{enumerate} and ENTER, in other application like texmaker, the \end{enumerate} will auto-completed; 
or I type in \sec, there should be some suggestion like \section{}.

Does sublime text2 latextools has related functions? or other solutions?

Comment: You may want to try snippets. With LaTeXTools, if I type, e.g., `begin` and hit `tab`, it creates a `\begin{something}...\end{something}` for me, allowing me to change the `something` to what I want using multiple cursors. You could easily define a new snippet to complete `\sec` to `\section{something}`.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same need. latextools may not be fully developed yet. At least the autocompletion part is not completely done compared to the one I used. (I had been using AUCTeX in Emacs.)

For now, you may reduce your typing by using **ctrl+l, e** command for creating environments.

type the name of an environment, such as 'enumerate', and then type ctrl+l, e. That should complete the block.